# Merge Sort Issues

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Hello everyone I am currently working on implementing a merge sort algorithim and I have gotten my code to work, but there is still something wrong with my work. For example when I enter "1 3 5 2" , I receive back "1 3 5 5". I would like some help locating my error as I am unable to do so even with cerr statements. Thank You

```
vector<int> VectorOps::mergeSort(vector<int> toSort)
{
if (toSort.size() <= 1)
{
return toSort;

}

std::vector<int>::iterator middle = toSort.begin() + (toSort.size() / 2);

vector<int> left(toSort.begin(), middle);
vector<int> right(middle, toSort.end());
left = mergeSort(left);
right = mergeSort(right);
cerr << "The numbers are "<< endl;
return merge(left, right);

}


vector<int> merge(const vector<int>& left, const vector<int>& right)
{

    vector<int> toReturn;
    unsigned left_it = 0, right_it = 0;

    while(left_it < left.size() && right_it < right.size())
     {



    if(left[left_it] < right[right_it])
     {  
    toReturn.push_back(left[left_it]);
    left_it++;


     }
    else
     {

      toReturn.push_back(left[left_it]);
      right_it++;
     }
   } 
    while(left_it < left.size())
    {
        toReturn.push_back(left[left_it]);
        left_it++;
    }

    while(right_it < right.size())
    {
      toReturn.push_back(right[right_it]);
      right_it++;

    }




return toReturn;

}
```

Comment: You can also post this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

In the first conditional of `merge`, both branches have

```
toReturn.push_back(left[left_it]);
```

One of them should be

```
toReturn.push_back(right[right_it]);
```

And that is why copy and paste is considered harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Change `toReturn.push_back(left[left_it]);` to `toReturn.push_back(left[right_it]);`